# Kivy - lack of the top bar and window stretching functionality

Tags: python, kivy

**Software Versions**

- Python: 3.9.7
- OS: Windows 10
- Kivy: 2.0.0
- Kivy installation method: pip

I have a fresh install of kivy and this is my beginnings with this frimware.
When I run any kivy program I don't see the top bar and window resize functionality.
I looked at a lot of tutorials and this functionality is by default everywhere. Why is it not on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your kivy config file:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.kivy\config.ini
(C:\Users\your_username\.kivy\config.ini)
```

There you should find following settings for window mode and resize ability:

```
[graphics]
display = -1
fullscreen = 0
height = 600
left = 0
maxfps = 60
multisamples = 2
position = auto
rotation = 0
show_cursor = 1
top = 0
width = 800
resizable = 1
borderless = 0
window_state = visible
minimum_width = 0
minimum_height = 0
min_state_time = .035
allow_screensaver = 1
shaped = 0
```